# app crashes after xib edit

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, xib

I have a navigation controller app. I created a RootViewController class with Xib file. In that xib file I had table view and nothing more else. Toolbar and buttons on the toolbar I created in program way. Table view had datasourse and delegate File Owner.

I deleted this xib file, and created a new one with previous name. Created it like viewBased xib file and then I dropped down to it table view, toolbar, two buttons on toolbar. Add outlets on them. Saved it all. Clear all targets. Build all. And Run. Application crashes on start! Anyone know where may be the problem? Thanx!

Stack:

```
    [Session started at 2010-11-16 15:00:52 +0200.]
2010-11-16 15:00:53.729 PhoneBook[16210:207] ******* Accessibility Status Changed: On
2010-11-16 15:00:53.755 PhoneBook[16210:207] ********** Loading AX for: com.yourcompany.PhoneBook ************
2010-11-16 15:00:53.798 PhoneBook[16210:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "RootViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02510b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0266040e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x024c9238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024c91aa +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
    4   UIKit                               0x0036aa40 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
    5   UIKit                               0x00368675 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    6   UIKit                               0x004c1c8c -[UITableViewController loadView] + 80
    7   UIKit                               0x0036854f -[UIViewController view] + 56
    8   UIKit                               0x003669f4 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    9   UIKit                               0x003767e2 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    10  UIKit                               0x00374ea3 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0037612d -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    12  UIKit                               0x00370ccd -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    13  UIKit                               0x0048db55 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0456a481 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0456a1b1 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    16  QuartzCore                          0x045632e0 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 302
    17  QuartzCore                          0x04563040 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    18  UIKit                               0x002c104e -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
    19  UIKit                               0x002c1477 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 545
    20  UIKit                               0x002cb3ec -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
    21  UIKit                               0x002c3b3c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    22  UIKit                               0x002c89bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x02d6c822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x024f1ff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x02452807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0244fa93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0244f350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0244f271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    29  UIKit                               0x002c0c6d -[UIApplication _run] + 625
    30  UIKit                               0x002ccaf2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    31  PhoneBook                           0x00002494 main + 102
    32  PhoneBook                           0x00002425 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Have you connected everything up properly? Have you connected the view?

Can I see the code in your .m file please?

Comment: Thanx! the problem was in that I don't connected my view to Files Owner. And my files owner pointed to NSObject but not my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "RootViewController" nib but the
>   view outlet was not set.'

Your view controller lost connection for view outlet, you need to restore it in IB (as you do with all outlets)